# How do I combine $-\ln(a)-\ln(b)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm trying to combine this $$-\ln(a)-\ln(b)$$ into $$-\ln(\frac{a}{b})$$ but it doesn't seem to work like that. How would I combine the two logarithms into one? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try with, say, $a=b=2$. Is this true in this case?

Comment: Factor out the $-1$ first.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I factor out the $-1$ it's $(-1)(\ln(a)+\ln(b))$ which can be combined into $-\ln(ab)$ so $$-\ln(a)-\ln(b)=-\ln(ab)$$

Comment: Note, if you like, you can continue with $$-\ln(ab)=\ln\left(1\over ab\right)$$

Comment: I recommend using the command \ln. That's also what Barry Cipra did.